# Openfire archive list count is always 0

Tags: xmpp, archive, openfire

I am using openfire (3.7.1) with [monitoring plugin](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/monitoring/readme.html) (1.3.0) and am trying to determine if archive is set up correctly. "Archive one-to-one chats" option is selected in archiving settings. In adium xml console I send following xml:

```
<iq type='get' id='my-1'>
  <list xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive' with='user@my-server/resource/'>
    <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
      <max>30</max>
    </set>
  </list>
</iq>
```

Response I get is:

```
<iq xmlns='jabber:client' type='result' id='my-1' to='user@my-server/resource'>
  <list xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive'>
    <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
      <count>0</count>
    </set>
  </list>
</iq>
```

But when I check Openfire archive there are a lot conversations for specified user. I don't know how to check if my request or setup is wrong.

UPDATE: Also when I send preferences request, I get 501 error. It is very weird since probably if it was really not implemented, `list` request should also fail. Am I missing something?

```
<iq type="get" id="pref1">
  <pref xmlns="urn:xmpp:archive"/>
</iq>

<iq type="error" id="pref1" to="user@my-server/resource">
  <error type="cancel" code="501">
    <feature-not-implemented xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
  </error>
</iq>
```

UPDATE 2:

This is my `disco` response, where clearly there is archive feature `<feature var="urn:xmpp:archive:auto"/>`. I don't have any more ideas, what to check next.

```
<iq from="my-server" type="result" id="info1" to="user@my-server/resource">
  <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info">
    <identity category="server" type="im" name="Openfire Server"/>
    <identity category="pubsub" type="pep"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#manage-subscriptions"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#modify-affiliations"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retrieve-default"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#collections"/>
    <feature var="jabber:iq:private"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"/>
    <feature var="vcard-temp"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#publish"/>
    <feature var="urn:xmpp:archive:auto"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#subscribe"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retract-items"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/offline"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#meta-data"/>
    <feature var="jabber:iq:register"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retrieve-subscriptions"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#default_access_model_open"/>
    <feature var="jabber:iq:roster"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#config-node"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/address"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#publisher-affiliation"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#item-ids"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#instant-nodes"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/commands"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#multi-subscribe"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#outcast-affiliation"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#get-pending"/>
    <feature var="google:jingleinfo"/>
    <feature var="jabber:iq:privacy"/>
    <feature var="urn:xmpp:archive:manage"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#subscription-options"/>
    <feature var="jabber:iq:last"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#create-and-configure"/>
    <feature var="urn:xmpp:ping"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retrieve-items"/>
    <feature var="jabber:iq:time"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#create-nodes"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#persistent-items"/>
    <feature var="jabber:iq:version"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#presence-notifications"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retrieve-affiliations"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#delete-nodes"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#purge-nodes"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/>
    <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm"/>
  </query>
</iq>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated monitoring plugin version to 1.3.1-rc1 and it works now. I am quite sure that this was the revert of XmppDateTimeFormat integration specified in changelog:

```
OF-611 - Monitoring plugin 1.3.0 is not updating IDs of older archived messages.
OF-646 - Reverts XmppDateTimeFormat integration which broke querying via XEP-0136.
OF-664 - Monitoring archive shows null in room chat logs.
```